# Is it possible to connect to a cellular network using an external SIM card reader?

Tags: hardware, sim-card, cellular-network

I know that external SIM card readers exist for reading data off a SIM card. If a phone's internal SIM card reader was damaged or if someone just wanted to add dual SIM capabilities to a phone, could they do so by connecting the phone to an external SIM card reader?

Or is the phone's cellular hardware (e.g. antennas and transceivers) programmed to only interface with the phone's internal SIM card reader?

Comment: I think you should ask this on https://electronics.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 0):

No, A Phone is closely coupled to its own card reader.

If you connect a SIM card reader to a phone, it might theoretically be possible to use it, but you would need custom software for the phone. It would not be supported natively.